# How to render mustache template locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I am trying to use mustache and jQuery to import a JSON and create a html template.

I have followed tutorials to get to this point, but nothing shows in the browser and there are no error messages.

HTML

```
div id="repeatcontent"/div
```

Script: I import mustache, greate the template script and then use javascript to import the JSON.

```
 <script src=mustache.min.js></script>

<script id="tutorials" type="text/template">
        {{#a_tutorials}}
            <p>{{title}}<p/>
        {{/a_tutorials}}
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $.getJSON('audacity_tutorials.JSON', function(data) {
                var template1 = $('#tutorials').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template1, data);
                $('#repeatcontent').html(html);
            });
        });
</script>
```

JSON

```
{   
    "A_tutorials" : [
        {
             "Title" : "Binary",
        },
        {
             "Title" : "Clipping", 
        }
     ]
}
```

There are no error messages, and the screen is completely blank. I have also used console.log to try and figure it out but it returns all the data I ask it for.

Comment: how are you serving this webpage? are you opening the file or using a webserver?

Comment: I'm just opening the file

Comment: You'll need to run a basic web server. You can't make `ajax` requests with the file protocol. Try using this: http://simbco.github.io/httpster/

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes are:

- **A_tutorials** in json file while you use **a_tutorials** in js
- **Title** in json file while you use **title**
- your json file is incorrect. For instance this line

  "Title" : "Binary",

must be changed with:

```
"Title" : "Binary"
```

You may test json online by yourself.

Mustache is case sensitive.

```js
// $.getJSON('z.json', function(data) {
  var data = {
  "A_tutorials" : [
    {
      "Title" : "Binary"
    },
    {
      "Title" : "Clipping"
    }
  ]
};
  
  
  var template1 = $('#tutorials').html();
  var html = Mustache.to_html(template1, data);
  $('#repeatcontent').html(html);
// });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script id="tutorials" type="text/template">
  {{#A_tutorials}}
  <p>{{Title}}<p/>
  {{/A_tutorials}}
</script>

<div id="repeatcontent"></div>
```